# Is the decomposition of finitely dimensional representation of a semisimple Lie algebra into irreducible ones unique?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading Humphreys's book GTM9 on Lie algebra representations. The question above seems quite natural but the book doesn't give any clues on this topic, as far as I can see. Let's adopt the settings in the book: algebracally closed field with characteristic 0, finitely dimensional semisimple Lie algebra, and finitely dimensional represetations. Here by unique we mean the decomposition is unique up to order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is unique up to order. You can see this by observing that the number of times an irreducible representation $S$ appears as a summand in a representation $V$ is exactly $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}(S,V)$ (by Schur lemma). And the latter expression is independent of the choice of decomposition of $V$ into simples.

EDIT: As Jason DeVito suggested in the comments, uniqueness does not mean that you can find unique simple submodules of $V$ that make the decomposition of $V$ into simples. But the simples are unique up to isomorphism, of course. (And in fact unique in the strong sense if and only if all the multiplicities are $1$.)

Comment: (+1) I agree that the list of irreducibles and their multiplicities is unique (cf your answer), but in general, the decomposition of a representation $V$ into irreducibles is only unique if all the multiplicities are $1$.  For example, if $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by negating the first coordinate, then the only decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}(1,0)\oplus \mathbb{R}(0,1)$.  On the other hand, if $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by negating both coordinates, then any decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into two $1$-subspaces is valid.

Comment: If a multiplicity of $S$ in $V$ is greater than one, then $V$ contains uncountably many submodules isomorphic to $S$. Is this what you meant?
In that case, the decomposition can almost never be unique outside the multiplicity one case.

Comment: But usually one only asks if the summands in two different decompositions are isomorphic (up to a permutation). Asking that the summands coincide as submodules of $V$ is too strict.

Comment: I agree with everything you just wrote.  My comment was more for the original poster:  It wasn't clear to me what the OP meant by "Is the decomposition....unique".  I was pointing out that in the multiplicity 1 case, the answer is "yes", but in general the answer is "it depends on what you mean by unique".

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the question is not unique.

Literally understood I'd say that the answer is no, as soon as one irreducible occurs with multiplicity $\ge 2$. For instance, if $V$ is irreducible, then $V\oplus V$ decomposes both as the given sum, and as the sum of $V\times\{0\}$ plus the submodule $\{(tv,v):v\in V\}$ for each given scalar $t$, yielding, up to order as many decompositions as scalars.

When there is no multiplicity $\ge 2$, the decomposition is indeed unique up to order (i.e., the (unordered) set of summands is unique: these are precisely the irreducible subrepresentations).

What is true however is a weaker form of uniqueness occurring in general, namely up to isomorphism. Namely for every finite-dimensional representation $V$ with two irreducible decompositions $V=\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i=\bigoplus_{j\in J}W_j$, there is a bijection $\sigma:I\to J$ such that $V_i$ and $W_{\sigma(i)}$ are isomorphic representations for each $i$.